# Render hg.tar into in-memory tree-structure after getting back from MongoDB

Tags: python, file, mongodb, mercurial

I am working on a project where I have to store `.hg` directories. The easiest way is to pack the `.hg` into `hg.tar`. I save it in MongoDB's GridFS filesystem.

If I go with this plan, I have to read the tar out.

```
import tarfile, cStringIO as io
repo = get_repo(saved_repo.id)
ios = io.StringIO()
ios.write(repo.hgfile.read())
ios.seek(0)

tar = tarfile.open(mode='r', fileobj=ios)
members = tar.getmembers()

#for info in members:
#    tar.extract(info.name, '/tmp')
for file in members:
    print file.name, file.isdir()
```

This is a working code. I can get all the files and directories names as the loop continues.

My question is how do I extract this tar into a valid, file-system like directory. I can `.extractfile` individually into memory, but if I want to feed into Mercurial API, I probably need the entire directory as in a single DIRECTORY `.hg` in memory like how they exist in the filesystem.

Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way would be to extract the tar and run hg by calling the command-line tools.  If you want to be certain there is no unnecessary disk access, do it inside `/dev/shm` (on Linux).

Comment: @ArminRigo Yeah. That's what si01 suggested on the IRC channel. Either that or fuse file system. I can't. If there's no disk I can't even guarantee the access of hg command. Have to be done all in memory. Thanks though.

Comment: Ah, then you want to use the Mercurial API from Python, but have it not try to read any file.  You can do it with fuse, but also in the language itself, by masquerading the OS and file functions.  I don't know it, but there might be a library out there that does it for you.  (Obviously you can also go and patch the part of the mercurial package that you use...)

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial has a concept called `opener` that's used to abstract filesystem access. I first looked at http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/tip/mercurial/revlog.py to see if you can replace the revlog class (which is the base class for changelog, manifest log and filelogs), but recent versions of Mercurial also have a VFS abstraction layer. It can be found in http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/8c64c4af21a4/mercurial/scmutil.py#l202 and is used by the `localrepo.localrepository` class for all file access.

Comment: If this works as you suggest, the VFS interface could be written to run GridFS file commands. I wonder if a mercurial repo could be run directly from a Mongo database, but without the need for tar as OP proposed?

Comment: Yeah, that should be possible.